# ProgressBar não muda de cor

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou com esse problema de mudar de cor.

### Código:

```
    <ProgressBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:indeterminateTint="#00bfff"/>
```

Aparece que mudou de cor, mas na hora de execução não muda.

Answer (score 1):

Já tentou utilizar um ColorFilter no seu código pra 'pintar' sua progressBar?

```
(ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar))
    .getIndeterminateDrawable()
    .setColorFilter(Color.RED, Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Você pode dar uma olhada a respeito da classe em,
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/ColorFilter.html

Comment: cara, pra mim aqui não apareceu essa opção de getIndeterminateDrawablw

Comment: getProgressDrawable(), no seu caso!

Answer (score 1):

Altere o estilo do seu ProgressBar e adicione om Drawable `android:progressDrawable` como o exemplo abaixo e crie um arquivo de Drawable como no exemplo.

```
<ProgressBar
  style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/blueprogressbar"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Arquivo de layout drawable. Código abaixo deve ficar na pasta Layout com o nome blueprogressbar.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background">
    <shape>
        <corners android:radius="5dip" />
        <gradient
                android:startColor="#ff9d9e9d"
                android:centerColor="#ff5a5d5a"
                android:centerY="0.75"
                android:endColor="#ff747674"
                android:angle="270"
        />
    </shape>
</item>

<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                    android:startColor="#80ffd300"
                    android:centerColor="#80ffb600"
                    android:centerY="0.75"
                    android:endColor="#a0ffcb00"
                    android:angle="270"
            />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
>
    <clip>
        <shape>
            <corners
                android:radius="5dip" />
            <gradient
                android:startColor="#338FFF"
                android:endColor="#003180"
                android:angle="270" />
        </shape>
    </clip>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/splach_screen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfrango"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
    >

    <ProgressBar
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/webViewProgress"
        android:indeterminateOnly="true"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:indeterminateTint="#e29700"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

assim deu certo pra mim